# Attempting to install R 3.4.2 via tarball in Ubuntu 14.04, No F77 compiler found

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, r

**Objective: Get R-3.4.2 Working on Ubuntu 14.04**

I would like to get R-3.4.2 working on Ubuntu 14.04. I've had no success with apt-get.

**What I've tried already**

*Installing Ubuntu 16.04*:

For reasons that escape me, the 16.04 installation doesn't play nicely with my computer--the installation crashes when it attempts to install GRUB and screws up the master boot record. To repair it, I have to boot from media and run an repair utility, at which point I'm back to square one.

*Using `apt-get install r-base`:*

It installs R-3.0.x and then attempting to upgrade to 3.4.2 using the instructions [from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04) failed. The initial install goes fine, but I have packages that rely on R 3.2 or higher that I need to execute some of my code.

Using the tarball from CRAN:

Opening the INSTALL readme gives the following instructions

> As you are reading this file, you have unpacked the R sources and are
>   presumably in the top directory.  Issue the following commands:

```
./configure
make
```

Running `./configure` returns

> configure: error: No F77 compiler found

which I Googled and came up with a link to this [question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720430/error-running-r-in-linux), which recommended that I install the latest version of gcc with `yum install gcc`, which I tried with `sudo apt-get install gcc`and received a message that gcc is already installed and already the latest version.

**My question**

What can I do to make the R tarball find the correct gcc compiler upon `sudo apt-get configure`?

Comment: gcc is the C compiler, F77 is the fortran compiler. try `sudo apt-get install gfortran`

Comment: AFAIK the `gcc` package doesn't provide Fortran capability - you'd need `gfortran` for that. However, I encourage you to use the binary package available from cran.rstudio.com (or the local mirror of your choice) via `apt`, which should provide `3.4.2-1xenial1`